# How to convert QWidget 's image format from ARGB32_PreMultiplied to ARGB32?

Tags: qt

How to convert QWidget 's image format from ARGB32_PreMultiplied to ARGB32 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "convert QWidget's image format"?

Internally, the raster engine does all rendering in ARGB32_Premultiplied.